# ¿Cómo puedo correr un proyecto existente de Node.js?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Descargué un proyecto de Node.js para el manejo de la api REST, el proyecto lo descargué desde github, como puedo correrlo desde mi consola, o de que manera puedo correrlo? Tengo instalado ya Node.js en mi equipo
El proyecto se encuentra en la siguiente liga

https://github.com/JanidHam/nodejs-api-rest-tutorial

Comment: Lo primero es instalar las dependencias con `npm i`. Luego, fíjate si el *package.json* tiene el script *start* configurado, en caso lo tenga, ejecuta `npm start`, en otro caso deberás ejecutar directamente el archivo principal de proyecto; por ejemplo: `node index.js`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En lo personal prefiero usar npm para instalar las dependencias, que es lo primero para que los módulos que el proyecto necesita estén y todo corra bien.

El procedimiento para que puedas ver en funcionamiento el proyecto, después de haberlo clonado en tu equipo es:

1. Entrar al directorio del proyecto
2. Instalar express si no lo tienes: `npm install express`
3. Correr `npm install` para descargar las dependencias especificadas en el package.json
4. Ejecutar `node app.js`

Allí ya se ejecuta el código del tutorial, aparecen los primeros errores debido a la configuración de conexión local a Mongo, pero esto ya es otro asunto, hasta aquí, ya tienes ejecutando el proyecto en node.

Comment: Creo quisiste decir: `npm install express`. El segundo paso está implícito en el tercero. Express también es una dependencia.

Comment: Es una dependencia pero más global, es un framework, por eso me pareció que merecía mencionarlo como un paso extra.

Comment: No es una dependencia global, es una dependencia del proyecto

Answer (score 1):

Entra por la consola al directorio del proyecto y ejecuta `npm install` para instalar las dependencias, luego ejecuta `npm start` para correr la aplicación.

Comment: **Nota:** hay algunos devs perezozos que dejan el script start vacío.

Answer (score 0):

Primero debes de ejecutar **npm init**, de lo contrario te va a crear la carpeta node_modules y los packages en tu directorio raiz

Comment: Creo que si pones algunos ejemplos tu respuesta quedaria mucho mejor!

Answer (score -1):

Para correr *este* proyecto:

**1: npm install**

Instala todas las dependencias para correr correctamente el proyecto.

**2: node app.js**

Levanta el servidor, en este proyecto está por defecto el puerto 3000 si no configuras ninguno.

Answer (score -1):

Lo primero es instalar las dependencias :

**npm install**

Debes tener instalado mongo una vez instalado inicias el servidor :

**mongod**

Por ultimo corres la aplicación :

**node app.js**

La aplicación esta corriendo por el puerto 3000 por tanto abre la sigueinte url en el navegador :

http://localhost:3000

En el readme del repositorio hay un tutorial :

http://janidham.com/blog/como-crear-un-api-rest-con-nodejs/

Si necesitas instalar mongo :

https://docs.mongodb.com/tutorials/